# Placing drain pipe below pavement

Tags: drainage, ground, digging

In this picture you can see a paved path separating a flower bed on the near side and a drainage trench on the far side.
The pavement sits in a bed of compacted gravel, and is held in place by two rows of curb, set in concrete.

I’d like to have a drain pipe with a diameter of 10 cm cross underneath the path.
Is there a practical way to do this without having to remove the paving, break up the concrete and prepare the ground for paving again?

[image]

Comment: Or this? [Conduit Underground - Ways for tunneling under obstructions?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47795/conduit-underground-ways-for-tunneling-under-obstructions)

Comment: Or this? [Running irrigation pipes under a large concrete pad](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55491/running-irrigation-pipes-under-a-large-concrete-pad)